# Probability of cards drawn from a deck

Tags: probability

> The cards are drawn from a well shuffled deck of 52 cards one after
>   the other without replacement. The probability of first card being a
>   spade and the second a black king is ?

Here, is my approach,
Upon first draw we got a black spade king
$$P(\text{first card is spade}) = \frac{13}{52}$$
$$ P(\text{second black king}) = \frac{1}{51} $$

Upon first draw we don't get a black spade king
$$P(\text{first card is spade}) = \frac{13}{52}$$
$$ P(\text{second black king}) = \frac{2}{51} $$
Now, the total probability,
$$P= \frac{13}{52} \frac{1}{51} + \frac{13}{52} \frac{2}{51} = \frac{39}{2652}$$

But the actual answer is $\frac{25}{2652}$

Comment: For the first case, the probability that the first card is $K\spadesuit$ is $\frac 1{52}$.  For the second, the probability that the first card is some spade other than $K\spadesuit$ is $\frac {12}{52}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upon first draw we got a black spade king
$$P(\text{first card is $K \spadesuit$}) = \frac{1}{52}$$
$$ P(\text{second black king i.e $K\clubsuit$}) = \frac{1}{51} $$

Upon first draw we don't get a black spade king
$$P(\text{first card is $\spadesuit$ but not $K\spadesuit$}) = \frac{12}{52}$$
$$ P(\text{second black $K$}) = \frac{2}{51} $$
Now, the total probability,
$$P= \frac{1}{52} \frac{1}{51} + \frac{12}{52} \frac{2}{51} = \frac{25}{2652}$$

Answer (score 1):

As one card is common in both.

So probability = $\frac{13}{52} \cdot \frac{2}{51} -\frac{1}{52 \cdot 51}$

= $\frac{26}{2652} -\frac{1}{2652}$

= $\frac{25}{2652}$